# how can I compare a string with several values?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Something like:

```
if (mystring == "a" || mystring == "b" || mystring =="c")
```

I was hopping to do:

```
if (mystring in ("a", "b", "c"))
```

is it possible?

Comment: Your example is wrong, you are assigning and not comparing.

Comment: Im not talking about arrays @DanielA.White, I know I can add the strings to one, but I believe there are ways to do it without

Comment: `var strings = [ 'js', 'java', 'css', 'html' ]; var search = 'java'; var checkindex = -1; if ( strings.indexOf( search ) > checkindex) { console.log('available at position : '+strings.indexOf( search )); } else { console.log('not available') }`
(or)
`var search = 'java'; switch(search) { case 'js': case 'java': case 'html': console.log('available'); break; default: console.log('not - available'); break; }
`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) like this

```
if ( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ].indexOf( mystring ) > -1 ) { ... }
```

---

**EDIT** With ES7 comes a little simplification. As of today just Chrome 47+ and FF 43+ seem to support it:

```
if ( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ].includes( mystring ) ) { ... }
```

- [MDN on `Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: thanks, seems to be the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks! Mister SIrko

Answer (score 5):

Using indexOf is first thing that comes to mind, however you have to keep in mind, that **there's no `.indexOf` function in older IEs** (so you would have to use your custom code to simulate it, or just go straight to something like [jQuery.inArray](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray) or [underscore.js indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf)).

```
if ([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ].indexOf( mystring ) > -1 ) { ... }
```

---

Side note: as you can see by looking at inArray definition in jQuery source, writing your own indexOf replacement is pretty easy. So like I said - write your own method, copy-paste it from other libraries or just use those libs if you want to be able to use indexOf in every browser out there.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it the old way

```
a = "a";
b = ["a","b","c","d"];


function check(a,b){
    i = 0;        
    for (i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        if (a === b[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(check (a,b))
```

note that [indexOf is a recent addition to the ECMA-262 standard; as such it may not be present in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) If you're going to use this with IE it will only work with version 9 or above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf`

```
[1,2,3].indexOf(1) will give 0
[1,2,3].indexOf(4) will give -1
```

So, you can check if indexOf returns -1.

Similar for strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this:

```
if (["a", "b", "c"].indexOf(mystring) != -1) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (["a", "b", "c"].indexOf(mystring) != -1) {}
```

This would be the best way, however it may not work on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your version is the fastest one for three chars, and the most readable.

With a little more possible values, you could use something like this :

```
var c;
if (s.length==1 && (c=s.charAt(0))>='a' && c<='c') {
```

But that's mainly for fun...

Answer (score 0):

Addtionally: you could create a String extension for the comparison:

```
String.prototype.in = function(){
  return  ~[].slice.call(arguments).indexOf(this.valueOf()) ? true : false;
}
//usage
var myStr = 'a';
myStr.in('a','b','c'); //=> true
'd'.in('a','b','c');   //=> false
```

For older browsers: this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) contains a shim for `Array.indexOf`

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
foreach (str in strings) { 
    if (mystring.contains(str)) { 
        ... 
    } 
}
```

may work.

Comment: contains? Not a function